# ¿Obtener valor entero de una consulta como arreglo Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Cordial saludo compañeros , resulta que estoy haciendo la siguiente consulta usando query builder en laravel:

```
public function getSocial_network_post(Post $post)
    {

        $query = DB::table('post_social_networks')->select('social_network_id')->where('post_id','=',$post->id)->get();

        return $query;

    }
```

De la cual recibo el siguiente resultado :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito obtener el valor entero de esa consulta y guardarlos en un arreglo de manera que se vea asi:

```
['1','2']
```

Alguna idea de como podria hacer esto?

Comment: talves necesites tratar el arreglo antes de devolverlo algo asi como 
foreach($query as &$q){
(int)$q;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependiendo de tu versión de Laravel, tendrías que usar **pluck** o **lists**.

Para Laravel >= 5.2

```
$query = DB::table('post_social_networks')->where('post_id','=',$post->id)->pluck('social_network_id');
```

Para Laravel < 5.2

```
$query = DB::table('post_social_networks')->where('post_id','=',$post->id)->lists('social_network_id');
```

Lists fue reemplazado por pluck en Laravel 5.2

Comment: Excelente men, me funciono a la perfeccion, muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegro @KevinBurbano!

Answer (score 2):

Lo que sucede es que al llamar método `->get()`,  retorna una `Collection`, Lo más sencillo sería usar la función [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-column.php) , pero antes debes convertir a un array que es lo que recibe dicha función, para convertir, solo lo harías con [->toArray()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-toarray)

El código podría tener este formato.

```
$query = DB::table('post_social_networks')
         ->select('social_network_id')->where('post_id','=',$post->id)->get();

return array_column($query->toArray(), 'social_network_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

intenta usando la funcion [values()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-values), de esta forma:

```
$values= $query->values();
return $values->all();
```

eso te debería retornar algo similar a: `[0=>'1',1=>'2']`

Comment: De esa manera, me da el mismo resultado que en la imagen de la pregunta XD